# i need font sizes in app not to get effected by changing Settings Font size

Tags: java, android

I have my app running well as per design when the font size is at "Normal" on Settings->Display->FontSize.

When i change the font size to Small/Large entire content is mashed up. My app is content intensive and this is badly effecting the app.

Comment: Perhaps you should fix your UI design to be more flexible when it comes to font sizes. If the user has changed the fonts to be larger, **that is what the user wants**.

Comment: @TheWanderer using sp is exactly what causes fonts to get upscaled

Comment: @TheWanderer , I want to keep the size of the app not changed if the user changes the font size of the moble settings

Comment: @Pawel , I want to keep the size of the app not changed if the user changes the font size of the moble settings

Comment: @CommonsWare , I want to keep the size of the app not changed if the user changes the font size of the moble settings

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android developer training on supporting different screen densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities):

> The sp unit is the same size as dp, by default, but it resizes based on the user's preferred text size.

In other words, *when the user's font preference is "Normal"*, `dp` and `sp` units are identical. It is only when the user changes the font preference that the `sp` units start to scale up or down.

That means that if everything looks good in your app now when the font preference is "Normal", you can just change all of your `sp` units to `dp` units. This will cause no change to your app when the font preference is "Normal", and will additionally make sure that nothing changes when the font preference is anything else.

Comment: I want to keep the size of the app not changed if the user changes the font size of the moble settings

Comment: `dp` units **do not** change based on the font preference. `sp` units **do** change based on the font preference. So, if you don't want anything to change, use `dp` units everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this is not encouraged, you can use `dp` instead of `sp` for your text size specifications.

Comment: I want to keep the size of the app not changed if the user changes the font size of the moble settings

Comment: If you need your text views (not all layout views) not to get affected by device font settings you should use `dp` instead of `sp`.

Comment: well, if i need alllllllllll tools in layout not affected what should i do ?

Comment: Have you tried using other units like `px`, `in`, `pt` or `mm`? But you'll certainly loose all the scalable dimensions features. More about Android supported dimensions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension).

Answer (score 0):

use dp instead of sp, here is why:

android devices have multiple screen sizes and the same device can rotate screen; for you your app to look the same on multiple devices the responsive design concept came to existence, which mean widget and text size should adapt to the new screen parameters. So dp is not responsive and will look the same no matter what the screen size is, while sp is somewhat more responsive and takes into the account user preferences settings for accessibility sake.